# Confirm Dialog not clicking cancel

Tags: java, joptionpane

I was making a Tic Tac Toe game and have a menu option exit. When you click on it, a confirm dialog pops up with  OK and Cancel. When I click ok, it stops running. But when I click cancel nothing happens and the dialog is still there. How can I include that in code.

```
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")) {
    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to exit?", "Exit Game", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
        System.exit(0);
    else if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        window.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.setJMenuBar(jmb);                
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it appears you are missing a closing brace to your else if but that may be a copy and paste error. Otherwise this is probably not the problem code as the dialog should disappear on its own when any of the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Try to improve your code formatting and you will see.. and post valid code

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")) {
    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to exit?", "Exit Game", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)}
        System.exit(0);
}
   else if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
     window.setDefaultCloseOperation(**JFrame(or)your panel**.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.setJMenuBar(jmb);                
    }
}
```

Comment: The DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE give me an error. Cannot find symbol - variable